# Хранилище Массивов

Tags: java, массивы

Когда создадим массив, например, типа `char`, где он сохраняется - в heap, stack или pool?

```
char[ ] ch = { 'a' , 'b' , 'c'};
```

Comment: Массивы хранятся в куче.

Comment: то есть в heap?

Comment: не смотря на то что сделали new или нет все таки хранятся в heap?

Comment: Литералы, в том числе массивов - это синтаксический сахар. Приведённый вами код будет скомпилирован в последовательность байткодов - `newarray` и трёх раз подряд `iconst`, `bipush`, `castore`.

Comment: ок понятно спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все объекты в Java находятся только в куче, она же heap. Ссылки на объекты могут находиться как в куче, так и на стеке.